# I Want to mix two colour and to make third colour

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a colour and its hex value is #ffff35 and I want to mix an other colour        to make third colour which is black(#000000). Please tell me which hex value colour to mix with it to make black.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you want, but about mixing colors I like the adobe site: _https://color.adobe.com_

Comment: If you mix **black** with anything that is **not black** the result will not be **black**, just as if you mix anything *not white* with *white*, you can't get *white*. This has a lot less to do with CSS than it has to do with [color theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_theory). However, for what you're trying to do, you might want to search for less/sass [color functions](http://jackiebalzer.com/color).

Answer (score 2):

Hex colours are more akin to mixing light than it is to mixing paint. #000000 is the absence of red/green/blue light and is hence black. Thus it is impossible to mix light to get black as black is the absence of light.

Answer (score 1):

short answer:You can't. you can use this to see that no matter what combination, if black isn't included it can't be black. This is also fun to find just the right color for a webpage, because it gives you different formats to find the color. [colormixer](http://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_mixer.asp)